# opkg create repository with multiple package version

Tags: yocto, opkg

What is the method used for distributing the same package but different versions through opkg. From what I understand opkg read an index file which it then uses to list and install the required package.

So far I have a repository that has multiple versions of the same package, but when I generate the index file it only has the latest version of the package. Thus the target platform cannot choose a specific version.

How can I implement this?

Comment: opkg-0.3.2 handles this, see [release notes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opkg-devel/XoN-b1lmIlE), `opkg install package=<version>` notation is used

Comment: Solved it already. Pushed a patch to opkg-utils  to generate a multi version package index and used opkg bins like you said.